# SQL Subquery - Max() after subgroup are summarized SUM()

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sum

I want to precede with a thank you for looking at this.  Appreciated. 
I am writing a subquery that I need to get highest revenue group for each customer after the detail items that make up the revenue groups are summarized.  So, this query needs to get to one record for each customer (would need handle ties to prevent duplicates in my main query).  Below is the subquery (with a subquery that i will need to join to my my query (not shown) on ACCOUNT_ID.  The subquery that sums works but then I need to get the record for every account by ACCOUNT_ID AND REV_CODE with the highest total AMOUNT.

Preview doesn't appear to line up correctly but will see.

```
ACCOUNT_ID   REVENUE_CODE  CHARGE_ITEM   AMOUNT
1234         0210          9011           938.49
1234         0210          8294           546.00
1234         0850          3953           32.50
1234         0850          1023           12.56
1234         0360          1203           1292.98
```

I need resulted but for every ACCOUNT_ID (not TOP 1 of all results in the subquery). Really just need the ACCOUNT_ID and REVENUE_CODE
1234        0210     1484.49

```
    SELECT
    RC_SUBQ.ACCOUNT_ID
    ,RC_SUBQ.REVENUE_CODE
    ,MAX(RC_SUBQ.RC_SUM)
    FROM 
            (SELECT /* SORTED DESC ON AMOUNT. I NEED THE TOP RECORD FOR EACH ACCOUNT_ID */
                HTR.ACCOUNT_ID
                ,HTR.REVENUE_CODE
                ,SUM(AMOUNT) AS 'RC_SUM' 
            FROM TRANSACTIONS HTR
            GROUP BY HTR.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID,
                HTR.REVENUE_CODE
            ORDER BY HTR.ACCOUNT_ID,SUM(AMOUNT) DESC
            ) RC_SUBQ

            GROUP BY
            RC_SUBQ.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID
            ,RC_SUBQ.REVENUE_CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` and window function `PARTITION BY` to enumerate multiple sums.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HTR.ACCOUNT_ID, HTR.REVENUE_CODE ORDER BY RC_SUM DESC) AS RowNumber
```

So, something along these lines:

```
(SELECT /* SORTED DESC ON AMOUNT. I NEED THE TOP RECORD FOR EACH ACCOUNT_ID */
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HTR.ACCOUNT_ID, HTR.REVENUE_CODE ORDER BY RC_SUM DESC) as RowNumber,
    HTR.ACCOUNT_ID
    ,HTR.REVENUE_CODE
    ,SUM(AMOUNT) AS 'RC_SUM' 
FROM TRANSACTIONS HTR
GROUP BY HTR.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID,
    HTR.REVENUE_CODE
ORDER BY HTR.ACCOUNT_ID,SUM(AMOUNT) DESC
) RC_SUBQ
```

Then, you can filter `WHERE RowNumber = 1` in outer scope

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you.

```
create table Transactions
(
  ACCOUNT_ID int
, REVENUE_CODE char(4)
, CHARGE_ITEM char(4)
, AMOUNT decimal(10,2)
)

insert into Transactions values
  (1234, '0210', '9011', 938.49)
, (1234, '0210', '8294', 546.00)
, (1234, '0850', '3953', 32.50)
, (1234, '0850', '1023', 12.56)
, (1234, '0360', '1203', 1292.98)
, (1245, '0970', '1238', 123.97)
, (1245, '0970', '1223', 166.03)
, (1245, '0560', '1239', 400.00)

select * from Transactions

select *
from (
select 
  HTR.ACCOUNT_ID
, HTR.REVENUE_CODE
, SUM(HTR.AMOUNT) as [RC_SUM]
, row_number() over (partition by HTR.ACCOUNT_ID 
                     order by SUM(HTR.AMOUNT) desc) as [ROW_NUMBER]
from Transactions HTR
group by 
  HTR.ACCOUNT_ID
, HTR.REVENUE_CODE
) x
where x.ROW_NUMBER = 1
```

Here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c8d8ec5eaabb3a9ae507cc08a730a87d).